# Cannot set Platform specific Margin in Release-Build

Tags: ios, maui

In my .NET MAUI App, I have the following Grid.Resources:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Entry">
        <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Keyboard" Value="Numeric"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="Margin" Value="{OnPlatform iOS='0, 0, 0, 0', Android='0, -5, 0, -3'}" />-->
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

In **Debug**-Build on an iOS-Simulator and Android it is no problem and this code compiles without errors.

In **Releas-Build** to Deploy on my iPhone, I get a Compile-Error "No Value for Setter" on the Margin-Setter. Even when I delete the iOS-Property value as it is default anyway, I get this error.

What can I do?

Comment: try specifying a default

Comment: Do you think like ```<Setter Property="Margin" Value="{OnPlatform '0, 0, 0, 0', iOS='0, 0, 0, 0', Android='0, -5, 0, -3'}" />```?

Comment: Yes. But rather than ask, why not try it first? Then come back and either add Your Answer if it worked, or if does not work, then add a new section to question showing what you tried, and the error that occurred? :)

Comment: That’s the problem when reading things while you are on your way outside away from your computer and not being able to check instantly 

Comment: @Jason - Thanks also for your recommendation using a Default which worked. Didn't have compile errors then. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually like to use an explicit approach to using `OnPlatforms` in setters and I even tried this on Release mode in my project and it always seems to work.

You can try it out and see if it works for you

```
     <Style TargetType="Entry">
            <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Keyboard" Value="Numeric" />
            <Setter Property="Margin">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                        <On Platform="Android" Value="0, 0, 0, 0" />
                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="0, 20, 0, 0" />
                    </OnPlatform>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
      </Style>
```

Comment: I tried with this syntax before which failed - obviously I had the wrong TypeArguments. It compiles without errors now with your syntax. I also tried with a default value and the following ```<Setter Property="Margin" Value="{OnPlatform '0, 0, 0, 0', iOS='0, 0, 0, 0', Android='0, -5, 0, -3'}" />``` which also worked for me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I personally like this since you are not forced to have defaults and it looks cleaner too

Comment: Absolutely agree with you :)